# Efficient code to search for a string in another string based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r

I try my luck by asking a question here as I do not find a better solution else where on stack..

In data.frame "id" I want to collect how many times their names been referred to in data.frame "test" based on how many times colName is occuring in colCiting conditional on colYear and colCitingYear. Example: if lok in colName har year 1 and it is cited in year 3 it should add 1 to id in year 3, if difference in colYear and colCitingYear is more than 5 it should not be counted.

The example code seem to be working but to slow. Any suggetions on how to speed it up? The real data set has about 500 000 rows of colCiting and 1000 id rows.

```
colID<-c("ewry","potta","potta","ewry")
colName<-c("lok","tro","hopp","asl")
colCiting<-c("lok trohopp","potta ar as","ewry","potta hopp")
colYear<-c(1,1,2,3)
colCitingYear<-c(6,5,9,12)
test<-data.frame(colID,colName,colYear,colCiting,colCitingYear)
cola<-c("ewry","potta")
id<-data.frame(cola)
    for (i in 2:15) {
      id[,i]<-0
      colnames(id)[i]<-paste0("y",+i-1)
    }

    for(z in 2:ncol(id)){
      for(i in 1:nrow(id)){
        for(j in 1:nrow(test)){
          for(k in 1:nrow(test)){
            if(as.character(id[i,1])==as.character(test[j,1])&test[j,3]==(test[k,5]+2-z)&(test[k,5]-test[j,3])<=5&(test[k,5]-test[j,3])>0&grepl(test[j,2],test[k,4])){
              id[i,z]<-id[i,z]+1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with

```
cond1 <- with(test, colCitingYear - colYear) < 6
cond2 <- with(test, mapply(grepl, colName, colCiting))

with(test[cond1 & cond2, ], table(colID, colCitingYear))
```

It's unclear to me what the exact conditions are so these may not be 100% accurate, but hopefully you'll get the idea.  Here calculation of `cond2` is still inefficient, and could be improved if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works but you can try anyway:

```
require(dplyr)

fun <- function(x) {
            y <- test[test$colID==x | grepl(x,test$colCiting,fixed=TRUE),] 
            z <- test[with(test,colCiting %in% unique(grep(paste(y$colName,collapse="|"),test$colCiting, value=TRUE))),]
            a <-rbind(y,z) %>% group_by(colID,colName) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>% data.frame() %>%
            mutate(ind = ifelse(abs(colYear - colCitingYear)<=5,colCitingYear,0))
            res <- t(data.frame((1:max(test$colCitingYear) %in% a$ind)*1,row.names=NULL)) ; rownames(res) <- x ; colnames(res) <- paste0("year_",1:max(test$colCitingYear))
            return(res)
        }   
do.call(rbind,lapply(cola,function(x) fun(x)))
```

Comment: the suggestion seems to work on the hypthetical data I provided. Thanks! However I have a hard time figuring out what all the pieces of code actually do. Could you please clarify what the bits and pieces actually do?